# Is f discontinuous in the graph?

Tags: calculus, continuity

[image]

(1). Would it be letter (D) since at $\lim_{x \rightarrow -1} f(x) \neq f(-1)$ it would be a removable discontinuity, and it would follow for $f(2)$ and $f(3)$ right?

(2)  Now on this one I'm stuck since the limit does exist but $f$ is not continuous. The only one I see that would be not continuous would be letter C. Would that be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers to both questions are correct.

In the first problem, there are removable discontinuities at $x = -1$ and $x = 2$ and a jump discontinuity at $x = 3$.

In the second problem, no limit exists at $x = -1$, $x = 1$, or $x = 3$ since the left-hand and right-hand limits are unequal.  At $x = 3$, the limit does exist.  However, $f(3) \neq \lim_{x \to 3} f(x)$, so the function has a removable discontinuity at $x = 3$.